# C# Diferença entre BeginAccept e AcceptAsync

Tags: c#, socket, desempenho, async

Qual a diferença entre as duas formas assíncronas? Qual tem melhor performance tratando de sockets e manipulação de milhares de conexão simultaneamente?

Exemplo para BeginXXX: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Exemplo para XXXAsync: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx

Comment: É interessante porque li na documentação que o Async é uma melhoria em relação ao Begin.

Comment: Resposta no Stackoverflow em Inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174423/c-sharp-socket-performance-with-net-4-5-async-vs-async-vs-begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nenhuma. Uma foi feita para atender um "padrão" de programação assíncrona e o outro outra.

Veja: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx

A primeira "Begin" é para atender a APM (Asyncronous Programming Model) e a segunda (BlahBlahBlahAsync) para atender a TAP (Task-based asyncronous pattern). A de Tasks é mais nova e mais simples de usar.

Em tempo, no meu blog: http://ericlemes.com você acha exemplos de socket server com ambos os cenários e algumas explicações sobre os ganhos obtidos com I/O assícrono em geral.

Answer (score 0):

Em questão de performance, ambos são iguais, a conexão é feita usando sempre a classe "Socket".

Porém no exemplo do BeginXXX, é uma solução mais simples, usando a forma básica do uso de Async.

No exemplo do XXXAsync é um exemplo baseado em eventos, este exemplo é mais completo porque nesse exemplo ele já espera até 100 conexões simultâneas como pode ser visto nessa linha:

```
listenSocket.Listen(100);
```

Para descrição do que você precisa, você poderia usar qualquer uma dessas soluções, porém a do XXXAsync já está mais próxima e preparada para o que você quer, repare que ele já é um exemplo de um servidor, basta implementar o a ações desejadas.

Agora, dependendo do que você for fazer, e de quem for consumir, você pode eliminar diversas preocupações da camada de rede usando WCF ou até mesmo WebAPI. Mas ai vai depender dos requisitos do projeto.